# renaming files in cmd using wildcards

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a BAT file for renaming some files.
My files are `*.jpg` where * is the file name and I want them to be `*-thumb.jpg`.

When trying to do `RENAME *.jpg *-thumb.jpg` my files appear as `*.jpg-thumb.jpg`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like:

```dos
for %%f in (*.jpg) do rename "%%f" "%%~nf-thumb.jpg"
```

Comment: More info here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg updated your answer - it was missing the original filename in the rename command.  Also added "'s to handle file names with spaces, and doubled the %'s so the command will work in a batch file

Comment: @shf301 thank you both for your answers and your answer updates!

Comment: And if you want to do this directly in a dos promt you need to use one (1) %

Answer (score 34):

Actually the RENAME command alone can solve the problem, as long as there is only one `.` in the name. Simply use many `?` instead of a single `*`.

```
REN *.jpg ????????????????????-thumb.*
```

Just make sure the number of `?` is at least as long as the longest file name that will be renamed.

You can ensure that names with multiple `.` are not accidentally named by using many `?` in the source mask as well. The following will rename "abc.jpg" to "abc-thumb.jpg", but will leave "abc.xyz.jpg" alone.

```
REN ????????????????????.jpg ????????????????????-thumb.*
```

You can rename a file with two dots like "abc.xyz.jpg" using the following.

```
REN ????????????.????????????.jpg ????????????.????????????-thumb.*
```

The pattern can be extended for any number of dots in the name.

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards) for more info.