# Highslide and image filenames containing ampersand

Tags: asp.net, highslide

I have a number of image files with filenames that include special characters - notably ampersand. In order to get Highslide to handle such file names, my code uses the .NET Uri.EscapeUriString or EscapeDataString utilities to escape such characters. As well as e.g. converting spaces to %20, etc., the second of these utilities converts an ampersand to %26 while the first leaves it as &. In both cases, I can copy and paste the generated url from a View Source window to a browser address box and see the image. So I have to assume that for some reason Highslide either cannot handle such characters or does some form of additional conversion which causes the final url to be invalid.

I suspect that there is a similar issue with filenames containing single apostrophes, but am still investigating that.

Is there a recognised way of dealing with this issue or do I have to rename all my image files (ugh!)?

Jon

Comment: See my reply in the Highslide JS forum. But Christian Duvall is correct - steering clear of reserved characters will save you all kinds of tsuris down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Ampersands are a reserved keyword and I'd suggest that you'll have far more problems leaving them in than fixing this issue now.

To fix in batch, check out:
    [renaming files in cmd using wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780097/renaming-files-in-cmd-using-wildcards)